# Select rows with the same order of values in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a dataframe with a column events that contains 3 values 'event1', 'event2', and 'event3'. and I'm looking for a way to select just the rows with events in a certain order ['event1', 'event2', 'event3'].

I tried:

```
df[df['Event'].isin(['event1', 'event2', 'event3'])]
```

but is gives as result the whole dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['event1','01:22:52.134'],['event2','03:21:31.123'],  ['event1','21:12:52.544'],['event3','23:12:31.216'],['event1','10:22:02.134'],['event2','06:52:48.184'], ['event3','12:52:46.188'], ['event3','06:52:46.184'], ['event1','13:33:46.235'], ['event2','14:35:12.235'], ['event3','14:59:12.177']], columns=["Events",'Time']) 
df
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need 3 conditons:

```
m = df.Events.eq('event1') 
    & df.Events.shift(-1).eq('event2')
    & df.Events.shift(-2).eq('event3')
```

Now shift the mask forwards:

```
df[(m | m.shift() | m.shift(2))]

    Events          Time
4   event1  10:22:02.134
5   event2  06:52:48.184
6   event3  12:52:46.188
8   event1  13:33:46.235
9   event2  14:35:12.235
10  event3  14:59:12.177
```

---

For any number of events, you can generalise with `np.logical_and.reduce`:

```
events = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3']
m = pd.Series(
    np.logical_and.reduce([
        df.Events.shift(-i).eq(e) for i, e in enumerate(events)
    ])
)
```

Followed by `np.logical_or.reduce` for the second step;

```
df[np.logical_or.reduce([
       m.shift(i).fillna(False) for i in range(len(events))
  ])
]

    Events          Time
4   event1  10:22:02.134
5   event2  06:52:48.184
6   event3  12:52:46.188
8   event1  13:33:46.235
9   event2  14:35:12.235
10  event3  14:59:12.177
```

Comment: Thank you ! your answer was very helpful